# Constrain the Intercept term in H2O GLM

Tags: r, regression, h2o

I'm familiar with how to [constrain the Betas](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/beta_constraints.html) (regression parameters) in an `h2o.glm()`, but struggling to understand how this can be extended to constrain the intercept.

(I do understand that [`intercept=FALSE`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/intercept.html) constrains it to zero, but I'm interested in a non-zero constraint.)

Notional example dataset:

```
n <- 100

set.seed(1)

getPoints <- function(n){
    rbind(
        data.frame(col= factor('red', levels=c('red','blue')), 
                   x1 = rnorm(n=n,mean=11,sd = 2), 
                   x2 = rnorm(n=n,mean=5,sd=1)),
        data.frame(col='blue', 
                   x1 = rnorm(n=n,mean=13,sd = 2), 
                   x2 = rnorm(n=n,mean=7,sd=1))
        )
}

df1     <- getPoints(n)
```

Example constraints:

```
param_names <- c('Intercept', 'x1', 'x2')
param_vals  <- c(       27.5, -1.1, -2.7)

beta_const_df <- data.frame(names = c('Intercept','x1','x2'),
                            lower_bounds = param_vals-0.1,
                            upper_bounds = param_vals+0.1,
                            beta_start   = param_vals)
```

The constraints will work if I *omit* the "Intercept" constraint:

```
glm1 <- h2o.glm(x=c('x1','x2'),
                y='col',
                family='binomial',
                lambda=0,
                alpha=0,
                training_frame = 'df1',
                beta_constraints=beta_const_df[-1,] 
                )
glm1@model$coefficients
# Intercept        x1        x2 
#  27.68408  -1.00000  -2.60000
```

But if I include an "Intercept" constraint, the other constraints fail too.

```
glm2 <- h2o.glm(x=c('x1','x2'),
                y='col',
                family='binomial',
                lambda=0,
                alpha=0,
                training_frame = 'df1',
                beta_constraints=beta_const_df)   
glm2@model$coefficients
#  Intercept          x1          x2 
# 0.67783085 -0.01185921 -0.03083395
```

What's the proper syntax to constrain the intercept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `standardize` argument equal to False (shown in the code below), you can read more about the beta_constraints parameter [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/beta_constraints.html):

```
glm1 <- h2o.glm(x=c('x1','x2'),
                y='col',
                family='binomial',
                lambda=0,
                alpha=0,
                training_frame = as.h2o(df1),
                beta_constraints=beta_const_df,
                standardize = F
)
glm1@model$coefficients
> glm1@model$coefficients
#Intercept        x1        x2 
#27.6      -1.0      -2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround if all constraints are strict equality**

I can inflict severe L2 penalty `rho` for deviating from `beta_given`, and it seems like `Intercept` is supported here:

```
beta_const_df <- data.frame(names = c('Intercept','x1','x2'),
                            #lower_bounds = param_vals-0.1, #don't bound
                            #upper_bounds = param_vals+0.1,
                            #beta_start   = param_vals, # use beta_given
                            beta_given   = param_vals, # new
                            rho          = 1e9 )       # new
```

Then this works:

```
glm2 <- h2o.glm(x=c('x1','x2'),
                y='col',
                family='binomial',
                lambda=0,
                alpha=0,
                training_frame = 'df1',
                beta_constraints=beta_const_df)

glm2@model$coefficients
# Intercept        x1        x2 
#      27.5      -1.1      -2.7 
all.equal(glm2@model$coefficients, param_vals, check.names=FALSE) # TRUE
```

This only works if you have all equality constraints (not distinct upper and lower bounds).

Either way, still wondering if there is a less hacky way to do it.